# Phrase for order is done or order received?

Tags: phrases, technology

I am developing a mobile application, which gets orders from client and sends it to us. What I am wondering is what kind of a statement can I use in order to inform the user that we have received his order. It must be a short statement as well as informative.

- Order Is Done
- Order Received
- or??

Since I am not a native English speaker I think I need some help here :)

Comment: Order is done implies it has been received, packed, sent, delivered to the client, and probably billed as well. I would not say that at the moment you receive the order from the customer :) The common phrasing is indeed: "We have received your order and we will handle it as soon as possible."

Comment: "10-4 good buddy!" :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Order received" might be perceived as ambiguous, because it may not be clear whether it refers to

- the supplier receiving the order, or
- the customer receiving what he has ordered

"Order is done" is similarly afflicted: does *done* refer to what the customer does, or the supplier?

I would use ***Order placed***. This is unambiguously something that the customer does with the order.

The corollary for what the supplier does is ***Order fulfilled***.

Comment: To be honest I didn't understand this exactly, as a supplier can I say `Order placed` in order to let him know that we have acknowledged their order and will execute it soon?

Comment: Yes. If **you** say "Order placed" it means that he has sent it and you have it.

Comment: I think *order placed* implies sending the order from the buyer's side. I don't know if it implies reception on the seller's end.

Comment: @Noah The point is that if the supplier's status is shown as "Order placed" they have acknowledged that that is the status of the order. It's a two-word status which unambiguously defines which stage the order has reached in the process.

Answer (score 2):

**Order Placed**

then

**Order Fulfilled**

Comment: Jinx :-) -- by 11 seconds!

Comment: @AndrewLeach - ah yes good answer.  Damn proxy server.

Answer (score 1):

What about ( order confirmed ) in my opinion when the word Confirmed is applied in a form order it is placing support at the fact of full knowledge of this order by not only the app system but consecutively also by who ever is in-charge of receiving and processing what is to follow for this order completion.